# How to conditionally render based on a media query in React with SSR (Next.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a lot of components, that should displayed separately on different viewports. On client-side, there's `useLayoutEffect`. Here's how to use it without warning with SSR:

```
export const useLayoutEffect =
    typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document && window.document.createElement
        ? React.useLayoutEffect
        : React.useEffect;
```

It's ok if `useLayoutEffect` runs later after initial DOM render, when the bundle is loaded.
But I need to run it **before first paint**. It's necessary for conditional rendering using `window.matchQuery`:

useMedia.tsx:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useLayoutEffect } from './utils';

export const useMedia = (query: string) => {
    const [matches, setMatches] = useState(false);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const mediaObserver = window.matchMedia(query);
        setMatches(mediaObserver.matches);

        const updateMatch = (e: MediaQueryListEvent) =>
            e.matches ? setMatches(true) : setMatches(false);

        if (mediaObserver.addEventListener) {
            mediaObserver.addEventListener('change', updateMatch);
            return () => mediaObserver.removeEventListener('change', updateMatch);
        } else {
            // Safari < 14
            mediaObserver.addListener(updateMatch);
            return () => mediaObserver.removeListener(updateMatch);
        }
    }, [query]);

    return matches;
};
```

Another identical case is when I need to toogle the state before the DOM is rendered.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)').matches) {
            setOpenInfo(false);
        }
    }, []);
```

Which is not possible for SSR before initial render. For now I can use https://github.com/artsy/fresnel package, which seems to solve the problem, or in the future features like HTML Client Hints. Maybe there's some better approach I missed?

Comment: that sounds impossible to me, because when the server side rendering happens, you can not know details about the device where the page will be shown on. You might be able to send the needed information from the page that was previously shown (but even then the user might resize the window before the response comes from the server).